# Gradle Release Plugin for projects not following semantic versioning scheme

Tags: gradle, release, semantic-versioning, gradle-release-plugin, axion-release-plugin

I'm writing a components that will be working with some particular version of platform. Let's say the platform is in version 1.18.0, then I want to release component e.g. with version `1.18.0.1`, then `1.18.0.2`. If platform updates I want to release `1.19.0.1` etc. This of course breaks semantic versioning.

I need a release plugin for Gradle, that supports this versioning scheme, but it uses only tags to store version (no commits during release, so I cannot use https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release).

There are two plugins that from what I've seen enforce semantic versioning so I cannot use them:

- axion-release-plugin (https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin)
- nebula-release-plugin (https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin)

How can I achieve basically the same as axion-release-plugin but with my custom versioning scheme that does not follow semver?

Answer (score 1):

Actually https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release could do what you want.
Disable the tasks you don't need in your build.gradle

```
preTagCommit.enabled = false
commitNewVersion.enabled = false
```

At the end you should have only the tag in git. But why not having it committed to git? You will need the new version at least I think (would be commitNewVersion).

Comment: I don't want commits in Git as I don't want to pollute the history. In my case there is release after almost every commit. If I set properties as you recommend then how gradle-release will know what is the next version to use? Axion reads tags to determine that.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. When I look at the config documentation https://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/overview/ I think it should be possible to have custom version schema. Specify your own versionIncrementer for example to have your own schema. It looks highly customizable.